# Change font color of Gimp tool-tips - virtually unreadable

Tags: gimp

I am running GIMP 2.10.12 64-bit on Windows 10. The tool-tips font is virtually unreadable as it is a very light gray on a light yellow background. I know this can be fixed as I have previously found a solution for it but cannot remember what the solution was and cannot find it with Google searches. A solution that allows me to change the font color of the tool-tips would be appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and it is very hard to find the right answer.
I have actually found it.
Go to "Preferences" under Edit. Wait a few seconds for the Preferences to open.
Then under "Interface" choose "Theme". I prefer the System colors.
Under there are also the "Icon theme" button, I also changed that to "Legacy", since I prefer that over the "Symbolic" type. 
Hope this was helpful.